# GWT Dynamic checkboxes in UiBinder

Tags: java, checkbox, gwt, gxt

How to implement GWT Dynamic checkboxes in UiBinder. 
[image]

Here is my requirement: I should implement Dynamic checkboxes. The marked check boxes are not fixed, there may be more or less of them.
By using `<gwt:CheckBoxGroup ui:field="group1">`, I can implement fixed check boxes with static data like this.

```
                    <m:CheckBoxGroup ui:field="group2">
                        <m:CheckBox>11/17/2016</m:CheckBox>
                        <m:CheckBox>11/15/2016</m:CheckBox>
                        <m:CheckBox>11/14/2016</m:CheckBox>
                        <m:CheckBox>11/11/2016</m:CheckBox>
                    </m:CheckBoxGroup>
```

Can you help me implementing Dynamic checkboxes in uibinding.

Answer (score 1):

UiBinder is just a declarative XML template. In the [docs](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideUiBinder.html) you will find:

> It is not a renderer, or at any rate that is not its focus. There are
>   no loops, no conditionals, no if statements in its markup, and only a
>   very limited expression language. UiBinder allows you to lay out your
>   user interface. It’s still up to the widgets or other controllers
>   themselves to convert rows of data into rows of HTML.

So you need to add your checkboxes to the `CheckBoxGroup` with Java code:

```
@UiField
CheckBoxGroup group1;

...

CheckBox check1 = new CheckBox();
check1.setBoxLabel("11/17/2016");

...

group1.add(check1);
group1.add(check2);
group1.add(check3);
```

More examples [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/GWT/UsingCheckBoxGrouptogroupCheckBoxesExtGWT.htm).